# Python/Tkinter - Writing Button State To a File to Automatically Re-Apply on Next Startup?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, colors, text-files

I'm trying to save the state of a button's foreground color (changed by a user clicking on it) to a .txt file in order to automatically re-apply said foreground color the next time it's run. This is the code I have... toggle_color works perfectly, and so does it's ability to write the color status to the .txt file. But, it doesn't automatically change the color on startup. Meaning, I've probably messed up something on the last part. What did I do wrong?

EDIT: Forgot to call .read(). But `toggle_color(colors = ['white', '#0055C4'])` is not an accepted way of changing a previous definition. So, how WOULD I go about changing the colors variable of toggle_color?

```
 def toggle_color(last=[0]): #this is what toggles the fg color of the button
        colors = ['#0055C4', 'white']
        color = colors[last[0]]
        last[0] = (last[0] + 1) % 2
        savepass.config(fg=color)
        with open('loaderstate.txt', 'w') as loader_file:
            loader_file.write(savepass.cget('fg'))


savepasspic = PhotoImage(file="RememberMeBackground.png")
savepass=Button(root, font=('Arial Black',10),image=savepasspic, text="    remember me", compound=CENTER, command=toggle_color, activeforeground="#0055C4", activebackground="#303030", relief=GROOVE)
savepass.config(borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, width=120, height=18, fg='white', bg="grey")
savepass.place(x=105, y=287)

def blueoverall(): #changes the fg color of the button, and reverses toggle_color order
savepass.config(fg='#0055C4')
toggle_color(colors = ['white', '#0055C4'])

with open('loaderstate.txt', 'r') as loader_file: #should run automatically on startup and determine color of button fg
    if loader_file.read == '#0055C4':
        blueoverall()
    if loader_file.read == 'white':
        savepass.config(fg='white')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.read` is a method. You should call it.

Also, there is a chance read would return a value with a newline at the end which means you should `strip()` returned value to compare with color values.

```
if loader_file.read().strip() == '#0055C4':
                   ^^
```